# Can't return a global variable from a different module

Tags: python

Hello
I am making a script that consists of multiple modules.

I am trying to make a "live" image checker, whenever it sees the image i need, it returns value 1 to main file (i'll use this value later in the code). I don't know how to make it working at all times in parallel while the main code is executing (tried using Thread module but didn't work). The variable is "trapped" inside the loop.


Here is everything i have:

main.py:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import pytesseract
from threading import Thread
import check

check.result()
print(var) #check if it works
```

check.py:

```
import pyautogui
import time

def result():
    global var
    
while True:
    if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', region = (830,440,100,100)) is not None):
        print("i see the image") #checks if it works
        var = 1
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("i don't see the image") #checks if it works
        var = 0
        time.sleep(1)
```

when i execute main.py all i get is this output:

```
i don't see the image
i don't see the image
i don't see the image
i don't see the image
i don't see the image
```

First off i noticed python executes the code from module without being asked. Then it gets trapped in this loop madness. The var doesn't even gets a value assigned in main.py.

1. How to run multiple processes at once without the main function being interrupted?
2. How to update the global variable live on all files while being in a loop.
3. I know i did a lot of mistakes, please help me improve the code, maybe i overcomplicate myself

Thanks

Comment: When you import a module, any code not in a function automatically runs, unless that code is wrapped in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement. So, the moment you `import check`, its `while True:` loop is going to immediately start running forever. The `check.result()` line of code won't even be reached.

Comment: `main` can use `print(check.var)` if `check.result` were to ever return. (I'm assuming an indentation error in the question and that the loop is actually in the definition of `result`.)

Comment: Did you mean to indent the `while True:` under `global var`?

Comment: Or did you mean to delete the `while True:`?

Comment: "global" vars only have scope of the module where they are defined, they don't magically show up everywhere - if you want to use it from another module you still have to import it

Comment: @quamrana i followed this example: https://thewebdev.info/2021/10/19/how-to-use-global-variables-between-files-in-python/

Comment: @Anentropic if you pay close attention i already imported it under `import check`, where check.py contains the global variable. Or i did it wrong?

Comment: @RandomDavis i implemeted `if __name__ == '__main__':` as you said but it doesn't solve the main problem, i still can't get the live value from the loop.

Comment: @GeorgeRabus I'm not sure what you mean but that makes me wonder, do you think that the imported script can just run simultaneously and independently of the script you're importing it from? That's not the case. You have to use async/await, multiprocessing, or threading to do something like run a loop in one script while having another script run independently.

Comment: @RandomDavis yeah this is what i am trying to achieve, also the global var update

Comment: Running `global var` in `result()` does nothing. All that statement does is make it so that if you assigned something to `var` _from within `result()`_, _then_ it would update the global value of `var`.

Comment: @RandomDavis so what i have to do for `var` to get updated from within the loop?

Comment: You'd have to put the loop in a function with `global var` at the top. But of course the loop will never stop, so you wouldn't be able to read the variable's value unless the loop stopped, which it won't because it's infinite. I don't understand what your current code is trying to do - you're trying to just print whatever the value of `var` is the moment your script starts? Or is this just an example and your real code is going to grab that value at different points?

Comment: Assuming you want to have that code run independently and simultaneously, then you'd have to use multiprocessing or async/await. Both are very well covered with online tutorials so I'm not going to explain them here, but if you look up how to share state across threads or processes, via Queues or other types of variables, then you'll have plenty of info. Try a few tutorials and examples to get familiar with multiprocessing (or async/await or threading or whatever you choose), and then this'll be easy. This is a very simple use case of parallel processing but you need to understand how it works

Comment: @RandomDavis yeah, the code will grab the value at different points, depending on the value certain operations will take place. The loop is supposed to be infinite so it always generates value 1 or 0

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: So, I looked at the link and you seem to have omitted some of the key patterns: You don't assign to `var` within the `result()` function. You don't access `check.var` from `main.py`

Comment: @GeorgeRabus you did `import check` but you didn't import the `var` name from that module... so it would be available under `check.var` but you do `print(var)`  in the code above, which I guess gives NameError